# Find longest sequence of values by group in R

Tags: r, group-by, sequence

I need help identifying the longest consecutive sequence of values (=1) within groups of observations in R.

I have data on monthly rainfall in towns. I need to identify the longest period in each year when the monthly rainfall is above the annual average (rain_above = 1). If there are two periods of equal length in each year, I would like to identify the period with the largest total rainfall.

Some example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(town=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
                               "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
                               "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
                               "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"), 
                        year=c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,
                               2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,
                               2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,
                               2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001), 
                        month=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,
                                1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,
                                1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,
                                1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 
                        rain_above =c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
                                      0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
                                      0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,
                                      1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0),
                        rain = c(4.5,4,5,7.1,7.7,8,7.4,7.9,5.1,4.9,4.6,4.4,
                                 4.4,4,4.8,5.1,7.2,7.4,7.4,7.1,7.6,5.4,5.1,5,
                                 7.3,11.3,11.5,11.6,11.1,6.5,6.4,6.2,9.9,10.2,5.4,5.5,
                                 10.4,10.9,11.4,7.8,7.3,7.2,9.8,9.9,10,7.2,6.9,6.6)))
```

In df, town A has a rainy season in 2000 between month 4 and month 8. This is the only period of rain_above = 1.

Town B has a rainy season in 2001 between month 1 and 3. Even though there are two periods of equal length (3 months), the first period in this year has a larger total rainfall.

```
View(df)
df
   town year month rain_above rain
1     A 2000     1          0  4.5
2     A 2000     2          0    4
3     A 2000     3          0    5
4     A 2000     4          1  7.1
5     A 2000     5          1  7.7
6     A 2000     6          1    8
7     A 2000     7          1  7.4
8     A 2000     8          1  7.9
9     A 2000     9          0  5.1
10    A 2000    10          0  4.9
11    A 2000    11          0  4.6
12    A 2000    12          0  4.4
13    A 2001     1          0  4.4
14    A 2001     2          0    4
15    A 2001     3          0  4.8
16    A 2001     4          0  5.1
17    A 2001     5          1  7.2
18    A 2001     6          1  7.4
19    A 2001     7          1  7.4
20    A 2001     8          1  7.1
21    A 2001     9          1  7.6
22    A 2001    10          0  5.4
23    A 2001    11          0  5.1
24    A 2001    12          0    5
25    B 2000     1          0  7.3
26    B 2000     2          1 11.3
27    B 2000     3          1 11.5
28    B 2000     4          1 11.6
29    B 2000     5          1 11.1
30    B 2000     6          0  6.5
31    B 2000     7          0  6.4
32    B 2000     8          0  6.2
33    B 2000     9          1  9.9
34    B 2000    10          1 10.2
35    B 2000    11          0  5.4
36    B 2000    12          0  5.5
37    B 2001     1          1 10.4
38    B 2001     2          1 10.9
39    B 2001     3          1 11.4
40    B 2001     4          0  7.8
41    B 2001     5          0  7.3
42    B 2001     6          0  7.2
43    B 2001     7          1  9.8
44    B 2001     8          1  9.9
45    B 2001     9          1   10
46    B 2001    10          0  7.2
47    B 2001    11          0  6.9
48    B 2001    12          0  6.6
```

I would like to produce an indicator variable for rainy season, that is =1 during the longest period of months with above-average rain that has the largest total amount of rain, and =0 otherwise:

```
df1
   town year month rain_above rain season
1     A 2000     1          0  4.5      0
2     A 2000     2          0    4      0
3     A 2000     3          0    5      0
4     A 2000     4          1  7.1      1
5     A 2000     5          1  7.7      1
6     A 2000     6          1    8      1
7     A 2000     7          1  7.4      1
8     A 2000     8          1  7.9      1
9     A 2000     9          0  5.1      0
10    A 2000    10          0  4.9      0
11    A 2000    11          0  4.6      0
12    A 2000    12          0  4.4      0
13    A 2001     1          0  4.4      0
14    A 2001     2          0    4      0
15    A 2001     3          0  4.8      0
16    A 2001     4          0  5.1      0
17    A 2001     5          1  7.2      1
18    A 2001     6          1  7.4      1
19    A 2001     7          1  7.4      1
20    A 2001     8          1  7.1      1
21    A 2001     9          1  7.6      1
22    A 2001    10          0  5.4      0
23    A 2001    11          0  5.1      0
24    A 2001    12          0    5      0
25    B 2000     1          0  7.3      0
26    B 2000     2          1 11.3      1
27    B 2000     3          1 11.5      1
28    B 2000     4          1 11.6      1
29    B 2000     5          1 11.1      1
30    B 2000     6          0  6.5      0
31    B 2000     7          0  6.4      0
32    B 2000     8          0  6.2      0
33    B 2000     9          1  9.9      0
34    B 2000    10          1 10.2      0
35    B 2000    11          0  5.4      0
36    B 2000    12          0  5.5      0
37    B 2001     1          1 10.4      1
38    B 2001     2          1 10.9      1
39    B 2001     3          1 11.4      1
40    B 2001     4          0  7.8      0
41    B 2001     5          0  7.3      0
42    B 2001     6          0  7.2      0
43    B 2001     7          1  9.8      0
44    B 2001     8          1  9.9      0
45    B 2001     9          1   10      0
46    B 2001    10          0  7.2      0
47    B 2001    11          0  6.9      0
48    B 2001    12          0  6.6      0
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try it with `rleid` from `data.table` like below

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[
    ,
    `:=`(sum_rain = sum(rain), grplen = .N),
    .(town, year, rleid(rain_above))
][
    , rain_season := +(sum_rain == max(sum_rain) & grplen == max(grplen)),
    .(town, year)
][
    ,
    grplen := NULL
][]
```

which gives

```
    town year month rain_above rain sum_rain rain_season
 1:    A 2000     1          0  4.5     13.5           0
 2:    A 2000     2          0  4.0     13.5           0
 3:    A 2000     3          0  5.0     13.5           0
 4:    A 2000     4          1  7.1     38.1           1
 5:    A 2000     5          1  7.7     38.1           1
 6:    A 2000     6          1  8.0     38.1           1
 7:    A 2000     7          1  7.4     38.1           1
 8:    A 2000     8          1  7.9     38.1           1
 9:    A 2000     9          0  5.1     19.0           0
10:    A 2000    10          0  4.9     19.0           0
11:    A 2000    11          0  4.6     19.0           0
12:    A 2000    12          0  4.4     19.0           0
13:    A 2001     1          0  4.4     18.3           0
14:    A 2001     2          0  4.0     18.3           0
15:    A 2001     3          0  4.8     18.3           0
16:    A 2001     4          0  5.1     18.3           0
17:    A 2001     5          1  7.2     36.7           1
18:    A 2001     6          1  7.4     36.7           1
19:    A 2001     7          1  7.4     36.7           1
20:    A 2001     8          1  7.1     36.7           1
21:    A 2001     9          1  7.6     36.7           1
22:    A 2001    10          0  5.4     15.5           0
23:    A 2001    11          0  5.1     15.5           0
24:    A 2001    12          0  5.0     15.5           0
25:    B 2000     1          0  7.3      7.3           0
26:    B 2000     2          1 11.3     45.5           1
27:    B 2000     3          1 11.5     45.5           1
28:    B 2000     4          1 11.6     45.5           1
29:    B 2000     5          1 11.1     45.5           1
30:    B 2000     6          0  6.5     19.1           0
31:    B 2000     7          0  6.4     19.1           0
32:    B 2000     8          0  6.2     19.1           0
33:    B 2000     9          1  9.9     20.1           0
34:    B 2000    10          1 10.2     20.1           0
35:    B 2000    11          0  5.4     10.9           0
36:    B 2000    12          0  5.5     10.9           0
37:    B 2001     1          1 10.4     32.7           1
38:    B 2001     2          1 10.9     32.7           1
39:    B 2001     3          1 11.4     32.7           1
40:    B 2001     4          0  7.8     22.3           0
41:    B 2001     5          0  7.3     22.3           0
42:    B 2001     6          0  7.2     22.3           0
43:    B 2001     7          1  9.8     29.7           0
44:    B 2001     8          1  9.9     29.7           0
45:    B 2001     9          1 10.0     29.7           0
46:    B 2001    10          0  7.2     20.7           0
47:    B 2001    11          0  6.9     20.7           0
48:    B 2001    12          0  6.6     20.7           0
```

Comment: Great answer, +1. But, silly question. Would this work if we had say two sequences of 1 in the same year and town, one sequence being longer than the other, but the longest sequence having a rainfall sum lesser than the other, shorter, sequence? i.e. we would have rain_season on the shorter sequence while we expect it to be on the longer;

Comment: @Maël I would say my code won't work in the case you described, it seems I misunderstood OP's requirement. I will update. Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: @Maël I guess it should work now :P

Answer (score 4):

I could not find something better than this. Use `rle` to get the longest sequence per `town` and `year`, and then use `data.table::rleid` and `sum` to check whose consecutive season has the highest rainfall:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(town, year) %>% 
  mutate(rle = with(rle(rain_above),
                    rep(+(values == 1 & lengths == max(lengths)), lengths))) %>% 
  group_by(gp = data.table::rleid(rle), .add = T) %>% 
  mutate(sum_rain = sum(rain)) %>% 
  ungroup(gp) %>% 
  mutate(rain_season = +(sum_rain == max(sum_rain[rle == 1])))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 48 × 9
# Groups:   town, year [4]
   town   year month rain_above  rain   rle    gp sum_rain rain_season
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>    <dbl>       <int>
 1 A      2000     1          0   4.5     0     1     13.5           0
 2 A      2000     2          0   4       0     1     13.5           0
 3 A      2000     3          0   5       0     1     13.5           0
 4 A      2000     4          1   7.1     1     2     38.1           1
 5 A      2000     5          1   7.7     1     2     38.1           1
 6 A      2000     6          1   8       1     2     38.1           1
 7 A      2000     7          1   7.4     1     2     38.1           1
 8 A      2000     8          1   7.9     1     2     38.1           1
 9 A      2000     9          0   5.1     0     3     19             0
10 A      2000    10          0   4.9     0     3     19             0
11 A      2000    11          0   4.6     0     3     19             0
12 A      2000    12          0   4.4     0     3     19             0
13 A      2001     1          0   4.4     0     3     18.3           0
14 A      2001     2          0   4       0     3     18.3           0
15 A      2001     3          0   4.8     0     3     18.3           0
16 A      2001     4          0   5.1     0     3     18.3           0
17 A      2001     5          1   7.2     1     4     36.7           1
18 A      2001     6          1   7.4     1     4     36.7           1
19 A      2001     7          1   7.4     1     4     36.7           1
20 A      2001     8          1   7.1     1     4     36.7           1
21 A      2001     9          1   7.6     1     4     36.7           1
22 A      2001    10          0   5.4     0     5     15.5           0
23 A      2001    11          0   5.1     0     5     15.5           0
24 A      2001    12          0   5       0     5     15.5           0
25 B      2000     1          0   7.3     0     5      7.3           0
26 B      2000     2          1  11.3     1     6     45.5           1
27 B      2000     3          1  11.5     1     6     45.5           1
28 B      2000     4          1  11.6     1     6     45.5           1
29 B      2000     5          1  11.1     1     6     45.5           1
30 B      2000     6          0   6.5     0     7     50.1           0
31 B      2000     7          0   6.4     0     7     50.1           0
32 B      2000     8          0   6.2     0     7     50.1           0
33 B      2000     9          1   9.9     0     7     50.1           0
34 B      2000    10          1  10.2     0     7     50.1           0
35 B      2000    11          0   5.4     0     7     50.1           0
36 B      2000    12          0   5.5     0     7     50.1           0
37 B      2001     1          1  10.4     1     8     32.7           1
38 B      2001     2          1  10.9     1     8     32.7           1
39 B      2001     3          1  11.4     1     8     32.7           1
40 B      2001     4          0   7.8     0     9     22.3           0
41 B      2001     5          0   7.3     0     9     22.3           0
42 B      2001     6          0   7.2     0     9     22.3           0
43 B      2001     7          1   9.8     1    10     29.7           0
44 B      2001     8          1   9.9     1    10     29.7           0
45 B      2001     9          1  10       1    10     29.7           0
46 B      2001    10          0   7.2     0    11     20.7           0
47 B      2001    11          0   6.9     0    11     20.7           0
48 B      2001    12          0   6.6     0    11     20.7           0
```

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate what `with()` and `rle()` do? I would like to understand that part

Comment: Yes. I think the best would be for you to take a simple example (say with `c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)`), and apply `rle` to it. `rle` basically computes the lengths and values of consecutive equal parts of the vector. `with` is just a shortcut. In the example, `with(rle(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)), seq(values))` would be the same as `seq(rle(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1))$values)`

Comment: Oh. So with `mutate(rle = with(...))` you just assign 1 to the largest group of consecutive rows with 1. Then group by that `rle` and `sum()` to compare in case there are two or more equally large groups and finally with that sum and rle groups you can assign the season == 1, right? Really clever shortcut, cheers

Comment: This is exactly that, yes.